# How to Migrate Magento 1.9 Module into Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, module, migration

I use some extensions, such as the extension Alpha search module in Magento 1.9 but this module does not exist for Magento 2, so I need to convert the module to Magento 2. Can you suggest any tool or tips so I can easily convert a Magento 1.9 extension to a Magento 2.0 extension?

Comment: it is possible, but not easier, try follow this: https://github.com/magento/code-migration

Comment: Hi @MichaelHa
Thank you give me suggestion.
But can I know how can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use code-migration tool: https://github.com/magento/code-migration

To use it, follow the below steps:

1. Download code from the above link. unzip and upload it to your home/user/ directory, not in public_html or another root doc directory.
2. login to your server via shell
3. Now go to the "code-migration-develop", where you upload the migration tool code.
   Run the following command in the root directory of this toolkit

   `composer install`
4. now go to the bin directory: `cd bin`
5. Execute command: `php migrate.php migrateModuleStructure /home/YOUR_USERNAME/public_html/MAGENTO_DIR ../`

   It will convert the structure and you will see these converted
   structure in the directory: `code-migration-develop/app/code`

Run below commands to convert Layout & Php code

```
Run php migrate.php convertLayout ../

Run php migrate.php convertPhpCode ../
```

your code converts complete.

Hope it helps!